# Javascript - how to remove domain from location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to remove the domain name from location.href using Javascript. I have links like: `http://localhost/App/User/UserOrder.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=MO` and I need to have links without `http://localhost` and in future without it's real domain name.

I will use those trimed links in Javascript function so I would like to trim it also in Javascript.

I have tried: `window.location.href.split('/')[2];` but I could only get domain form it. And I want to get rid of domain.

Any help here much appreciated!

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Use `window.location.pathname`. This gives you the path relative to the host. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location) for more details.

For any arbitrary URL, assuming that the variable `url` contains your URL, you can do:

```
url = url.replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '')
```

Comment: The block [^\/] doesn't need the escape so can be [^/]

Answer (score 17):

Rather than doing string manipulation on `window.location.href`, you can use the [other properties of `window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location). In your case, you want the pathname, the search and the hash:

```
console.log(window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash);
```

Answer (score 10):

I posted this on your other question as a comment but I might as well add it here too. You can use a replace with a regex, like this:

`location.href.replace(/.*\/\/[^\/]*/, '')`

Answer (score 6):

Things have changed a bit since 2011 when the original answer was posted.  Now you can use the URL Web API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

For your question, the following code:

```
let dummy_url = new URL("http://localhost/App/User/UserOrder.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=MO");
console.log( "pathname : " + dummy_url.pathname );
console.log( "search   : " + dummy_url.search );
console.log( "both     : " + dummy_url.pathname + dummy_url.search );
```

Generates the following output.

```
pathname : /App/User/UserOrder.aspx
search   : ?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=MO
both     : /App/User/UserOrder.aspx?id=949abc91-a644-4a02-aebf-96da3ac7d8e1&type=MO
```

The combined pathname and search fields is what you want.

As of Nov 2021 this is available in everything except IE and Opera Mini.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
window.location.pathname
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/zKruK/

Comment: `location.pathname` does not have the query string or the hash.