# Find and change a part of url after home url

Tags: javascript, jquery

Shopify is switching dots in product tags to dashes almost everywhere in urls. Except for when you add a custom filter, it pulls original tags with dots instead of dashes, which results in 404 when filtering after dot containing tag was picked.

I want to use JQ for finding and switching dots to dashes in url right after home url. 
Google didn't help much.

So, let's say there is a ul

```
 <ul>
 <li><a href="http://www.whatever.com/something/tag.with></a></li>
 <ul>
```

How do i find that "something/tag.with" with a help of jq?

p.s.
If somebody can point me to how i change that dot to a dash- that i'd appreciate it very much. But just finding it will help a lot too.

Thank you!

Edit:

```
<div class="collection-name">
      <a href="/collections/wool/test.dot" title="Wool"><i class="check-icon"></i> Wool</a>
    </div>
```

And there is also this piece of jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("div.collection-name a").each(function(){
  this.href = this.href.replace('yarn/', '');
});
$("div.collection-name a").get(0).pathname.replace('.', '-');
})
```

I've tried adding another  this.href = this.href.replace. Didn't work
Figured href is still rendered as a html://whatever.com and so on, so used it as you see above. 
So, yeah... Neither one of these 2 worked

Comment: Is this what are you looking for: `http://www.whatever.com/something/tag-with`

Comment: Use RegEx to find and replace.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945429/javascript-how-to-remove-domain-from-location-href and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843691/javascript-regex-replacing-the-last-dot-for-a-comma (just replace comma with \.)

Comment: EvoD, yes. Checking other links too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a regular jQuery selector to find the desired  tag, call [get(0)](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get1) on the result of that selector, and get the property `pathname` from the returned `element`. For example, the HTML you provided here has only one  tag, so it's pretty trivial to select it:

`$('a').get(0).pathname`

Obviously, in a more complex document, the jquery selector will be a bit more detailed than $('a').

To change all literal '.' (dots) into '-' (dashes), just use normal JS [string replacement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

`$("div.collection-name a").get(0).pathname.replace('.', '-')` works just fine, as you can see from the example code snippet embedded in this answer; further assistance would require you explaining how what has been provided fails to meet your expectation.

```js
console.log($("div.collection-name a").get(0))

$("#found").text( $("div.collection-name a").get(0).pathname.replace('.', '-') );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <body>
      <div class="collection-name">
      <a href="/collections/wool/test.dot" title="Wool"><i class="check-icon"></i> Wool</a>
    </div>
      <div>Found the value: <div  id="found"></div></div>
    </body>
```

Comment: could you plz elaborate a little on changing a dot to dash? Really new to JQ. Learning it trail and error so far. Thank you!

Comment: Hm. Added this piece of code $("div.collection-name a").get(0).pathname.replace('.', '-'); still no go. tnx for your time btw

Comment: I have updated the answer and the snippet to show that this method works given your example HTML; please clarify what it is that is missing.

Answer (score 1):

first get the value as TML said and then call string.replace method with a regex pattern

var oldurl = $('ul>li>a').get(0).pathname; 
var newurl = oldurl.replace(/./i,"-");

The replace line should work like below as well (not tested though)

var newurl = oldurl.replace('.','-');